# How to use mouseMoveEvent on paintEvent on Qt 5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter, qmouseevent

I'm new on Qt and c++, so I'm having some difficulties. I'm trying to create a widget that can get the mouseMoveEvent position and draw an ellipse on my pixmap on mouse position. Below you can see the code:

```
#include "myimage.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPen>
#include <QColor>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>

Myimage::Myimage(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setMouseTracking(true); // E.g. set in your constructor of your widget.
}



// Implement in your widget
void Myimage::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << event->pos();

}

void Myimage::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
    event->accept();
    QPixmap pixmap2("/home/gabriel/Qt_interfaces/OpenCVTests/Webcam_PyQt5/Images/Court_top_View.jpg");

    QRect rectangle(0, 0, width()-1, height()-1);

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawRect(rectangle);
    painter.drawPixmap(5, 5, width()-10, height()-10, pixmap2);


    painter.drawEllipse(pos(), 10 ,10 );
}
```

The mouse position is being printed on console, but no ellipse on image.

Could you help me?

Regards,

Gabriel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#pos-prop):

> **pos : QPoint**
>
> This property holds the position of the widget within its parent
>   widget.
>
> If the widget is a window, the position is that of the widget on the
>   desktop, including its frame.
>
> ...
>
> Access functions:
>
> **QPoint pos() const void**
>
> **move(int x, int y)**
>
> **void    move(const QPoint &)**

As we see this data we do not want it, a possible solution is to create a variable that stores the value of the position obtaining through `QMouseEvent` and update the painting through the function [`update()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#update), in addition the first time the Widget there should be no ellipse so we check that the position has been assigned through the function `isNull()` of `QPoint`, as I show below:

***.h**

```
private:
    QPoint mPoint;
```

***.cpp**

```
Myimage::Myimage(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);
}

void Myimage::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    mPoint = event->pos();
    update();
}

void Myimage::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPixmap pixmap2("/home/gabriel/Qt_interfaces/OpenCVTests/Webcam_PyQt5/Images/Court_top_View.jpg");

    QRect rectangle(0, 0, width()-1, height()-1);

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawRect(rectangle);
    painter.drawPixmap(5, 5, width()-10, height()-10, pixmap2);

    if(!mPoint.isNull()){

        painter.drawEllipse(mPoint, 10 ,10 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc. I'm trying to migrate from pyqt to qt. Your solution helped me again. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm reading some c++ tutorials, the language is new to me, but i'm liking. I'll read the documentation of Qt before continue building my ui. Thanks for the hint.